# find_first_not_of выдает разный результат

Tags: stl, c++

Есть функция

```
void TrimLeft(std::string& str, const char* chars2remove)
{
if (!str.empty())
    {
        std::string::size_type pos = str.find_first_not_of(chars2remove);

    if (pos != std::string::npos)
        str.erase(0,pos);
    else
        str.erase( str.begin() , str.end() ); // make empty
}
}
```

В принципе, понятно, что она отсекает слева символы chars2remove.
Если вызывать ее

```
TrimLeft(s, " ");
```

то все нормально работает. Но мне надо проверять не только на пробел, а и на другие непечатаемые символы, и тогда я вызываю функцию так:

```
char *cc = new char[7];
cc[0]= ' ';
cc[1] = (char)8;
cc[2] = (char)9;
cc[3] = (char)10;
cc[4] = (char)11;
cc[5] = (char)12;
cc[6] = (char)13;
TrimLeft(s, сс);
```

В этом случае, когда s="ольха" или s="осина" (первая буква в строке о), то pos = 1 и первая буква отсекается.
Не могу понять, в чем дело.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так логично все. Что хочет функция? указатель на массив символов. Ок, ему его дали. Но как функция `find_first_not_of` узнает, где конец у этого массива? Правильно, по нулевому сивмолу. А где в Вашем массиве `cc` нулевой символ? неизвестно, где то да и найдется. И что там будет, пока оно найдется - неведомо. Если не верите, вставьте после `cc[6] = (char)13;` вызов strlen(cc) и посмотрите размер строки. Он точно будет не 7.

Что же делать? Писать правильно!

```
char *cc = new char[8];
cc[0]= ' ';
cc[1] = (char)8;
cc[2] = (char)9;
cc[3] = (char)10;
cc[4] = (char)11;
cc[5] = (char)12;
cc[6] = (char)13;
cc[7] = (char)0;
TrimLeft(s, сс);
```

Конечно, лучше массив создать статический в памяти, а не создавать каждый раз.

Comment: спасибо огромное. голова два уха я) и была ведь мысль, да что-то не задержалась)на счет массива - тож согласна)

Comment: `const char *cc = " \10\11\12\13\14\15";` было бы гораздо проще.